# Class not found Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I install intellij idea 14 and tomcat 8, and i create a Spring MVC project with the default template.

I didnt change anything just configure my tomcat path in the IDE.

I tried to run my default application i saw in the Event log that compilation completed successfully, but if i go to localhost:8080 i get this error:

http://pastebin.com/cHgw4G0K

Whats wrong with my server, or app, or IDE config?

Here is my sourcecodes:

HelloController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
                model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
                return "hello";
        }
}
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

        <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
                <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

hello.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
        <h1>${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Why i got class not found exception?

Comment: Please add relevant code and stacktraces to the question instead of links.

Comment: Is there a page called hello.jsp under the pages directory??

Comment: Here is my project structure: http://s27.postimg.org/5ez57zwz7/intellisource.png

Comment: Magnilex i updated my question!

Comment: The error suggests that tomcat did not compile the JSP file ... It looks like an incorrect or incomplete deployment. You should try to stop tomcat, do a clean build, deploy and restart tomcat. I do not use IDEA but there should be commands to do things like that ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to update version of javax.servlet-api in your pom.xml. 
Just replace this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

to this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your mistake you missing jstl lib directory in .jsp files that's why your jsp giving error .

for using `${message}` you have to include jstl in your jsp like 
`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>`

This will solve your problem :)